# sidebar needs to have all categories but doesnt

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have an application where I have added a sidebar with a list of all the categories the products belong to.

The feature works fine but there is a problem.

The code only scans through the products on the current page and not the actual categories available. That is:

In my application there are say 5 categories (which there are) of products but on the current page there are only 3 products. So the code only shows me 3 categories and not the actual 5. 
How can I fix this? Does this have anything to do with instance variables?

Here is the code from application.html.erb

```
<div>
  <% a = [""] %>
    <h1>Categories</h1>
    <% @products.each do |product| %>
    <% a = a + [product.category] %>
    <% a = a.uniq %>        
  <% end %>

  <% a.each do |c| %>
     <p class="text-error"><%= c %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Migration files..

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table :products do |t|
       t.string :name
       t.text :description
       t.date :delivery_date
       t.decimal :price

       t.timestamps
    end
   end
 end

 class CreateCommentsTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :commenter
      t.text :body
      t.references :product

      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :comments, :product_id
  end

  def down
  end
 end


 class AddCategoryToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     add_column :products, :category, :string
   end
end
```

Routes..

```
resources :products do
    resources :comments 
end
```

The code is available at https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/sample-app.git

Might take u people just a quick look to answer this...

Comment: Do you want to show all categories in the system or all unique categories attached to the listed products?

Comment: @AmitPatel  I want to show categories in the system but one category should be shown only once.

Comment: If you have separate `Category` model mapped to `categories` table then `Category.select(:name).uniq` will return unique categories.

Comment: check my answer below. It is difficult to explain via comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have separate `Category` model mapped to `categories` table then `Category.select(:name).uniq` would have return unique categories.

In your case you have category column withing the table. So in that case

`Product.select(:category).uniq` would return list of Products with unique categories.

So now you template would be cleaner with:

```
<% for product in Product.select(:category).uniq %>
   <%= product.category %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Could you please also tell me how to make sure that on clicking the category the products belonging to the category appear on the left side.. Just a hint would suffice.. thank you   @amitpatel

Comment: `Product.where(category: "selected_category")`. Check http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form for end to end flow

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display all categories simply do

```
<% for category in Category.all %>
   <%= category.name %>
<% end %>
```

unless you are trying to display categories that have products attached to them

Comment: The above code doesnt help, sorry, it must be because there is no separate model called Categories. I have uploaded the code for everyone to see. It is at [link](https://github.com/abhishekdagarit/sample-app.git). The project is very easy to setup. It can clearly show where the problem is. There is only category for the present page and not all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your sidebar is also handled withing the same request as your rest of page layout (i.e. there is no separate controller action for it).

`@products` you would have used in two places most probably... one for getting products of the main page and one for getting all products... you might have to rename them and modify it accordingly...

Show more code if that doesn't helps...related to backed which is rendering the page...